# "RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of numpy.float32" When trying to learn ml-agents

Tags: python, c#, numpy, pip, ml-agent

Every thing works fine, i can start up ml-agents with no problem, but every time i click play in the unity editor i get "RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of numpy.float32"? I have tried every thing to resolve this error... I hvae python 1.10.0

```
 ml-agents: 0.30.0,
  ml-agents-envs: 0.30.0,
  Communicator API: 1.5.0,
  PyTorch: 1.11.0+cpu
```

[Picture of the CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPVO5.png)

I was expecting for my AI to begin learning.. As show at minut 29:40 to minut 31:00 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPFU30tbyKs&list=PLzDRvYVwl53vehwiN_odYJkPBzcqFw110

Comment: Please provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). Please do not post links to code and reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same issue. The solution which worked for me was by upgrading the numpy version to 1.22.0.

```
pip install numpy==1.22.0
```

Fair warning: The upgradation will give you an incompatibility error saying "mlagents-envs requires numpy==1.21.2", but you can ignore this as this will not cause any problems in running `mlagents-learn`.
Also please check the release documents [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/releases) to see all the versions you have to install.